# SUMIF looking at a range of text criteria AND returning blank if empty cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a `SUMIF` function on one sheet looking at a range of cells in `Column A` on a separate sheet (`EP 1`). If the value matches the value in a certain cell in `Column A`, the `SUMIF` function sums the numbers in another range of cells in `Column D` on the sheet `EP 1`. Here's my formula:

`=SUMIF('EP 1'!$A$3:$A$25, "" & A5 & "",'EP 1'!$D$3:$D$26)`

**However, I have blank cells in** `Column A`**, so I would like to add into the formula, *if cell (e.g.*** `A5` ***as above) is blank, then return a blank cell*. How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps?:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A5),"",SUMIF('EP 1'!$A$3:$A$25,A5,'EP 1'!$D$3:$D$26))
```

Comment: @AnnieMac, please be sure to accept pnuts answer as the accepted answer. Doing so benefits you, pnuts, and the entire StackOverflow community. Welcome to the site! :-)